# Filtering out duplicate and none values from Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

In a Django app, I can access user sessions and then get users_ids with `flat=True`. E.g. I'm doing:

```
Session.objects.filter(last_activity_gte=time_window).values_list('user_id',flat=True)
```

But the result is tainted by duplicates and `None` values. How do I perform the same query and filter out None or duplicates?

One way to do this is:

```
time_window = timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=5)
user_ids = Session.objects.filter(last_activity_gte=time_window).values_list('user_id',flat=True)
user_ids = [id for id in user_ids if id is not None]
user_ids = set(user_ids)
```

But I wonder if I could have achieved that directly while querying the DB, which would be faster. Performance is crucial.

---

If anyone's interested, I'm using https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions to be able to access Django session objects as ORM objects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To exclude empty user fields, filter by `isnull`.

```
(Session.objects
    .filter(user__isnull=False)
    .filter(last_activity_gte=time_window)
    .values_list('user_id', flat=True))
```

To remove duplicates, you can use `.distinct('user')`, but that works only on some database back ends. MySQL doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: Btw, is it fine to use `values_list` and `distinct` together in this way?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: or `.exclude(user=None)`